# Would you say "wanna" when you want something?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-usage

Would you say "wanna" when you want something? For example, "I wanna a new PC", instead of "I want a new PC"?

Comment: Only if speaking informally.

Comment: Only if speaking English. _Want a new_ is pronounced /wanənu/ in English.

Comment: "I want a new" -> "I wanna new" not "I wanna a new"

Comment: Well, John Lawler, in some varieties of English. It's /wanənju/ round here.

Comment: Ok, some lects palatalize. But /wanə/'s still the same.

Comment: No. 'Want a new' is not pronounced /wanənu/ in English (the sort spoken where it used to be based). The _t_ is pronounced here.

Comment: This is a pointless question. Obviously native speakers often discard the /t in both *want **to*** and *want **a*** (where the final vowel is invariably reduced to the neutral schwa /ə). The former is commonly written in eye dialect as *wanna* - the latter less so, but there are no "rules" for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

The most common use of **wanna** is for **want to**. So, wanna can be used like this.

```
 I wanna be a doctor.
```

shown [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv165.shtml)

But, there are some of the cases, where **wanna** is used for **want a**, as below,

```
 I Wanna New Room.
```

referred [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0399254056).

Comment: I'm getting two messages here. "No don't use it" and "Here's how you use it".

Comment: @Mitch Narendra is saying *wanna* = want to, not *wanna* = want a.

Comment: I have also provided the link (in my edited answer), for the proper usage of wanna, and similar sounding words.

Comment: Not true. _Wanna_ is eye dialect, intended to represent something as it is pronounced, not as it's spelled. In virtually all cases, the /t/s of formal /want tu/ are merged with the /n/ into an apical nasal flap that's representable by "nn". And so does the single /t/ of /want ə/, so they're indistinguishable in speech, and therefore indistinguishable in spelling, since **eye dialect spelling is non-standard**. So: bottom line, use it if you like, as long as it represents the spelling.

Comment: Narendra is wrong. That site (which has no more authority as to what "proper" is than you or I) discusses one use of "wanna". It says nothing about whether people actually say "wanna" to mean "want a" as well as "want to", and in fact they do so.

Comment: @Colin: I need examples, that can prove me wrong.

Comment: "I wanna popsicle for dinner"

Comment: No examples from you, Mitch. I need examples from well-known websites, suggesting me what you are saying is true.

Comment: @NarendraDroidWorm: the link is correct as far as it goes. Certainly the most common use of _wanna_ is to represent _want to_; but it says nothing about other uses, and in fact it's usable whenever the actual pronunciation is the same, whatever the syntactic construction. Many syntactic idioms like /'hæftə/ or /'yustə/ have special pronunciations that mark them as one particular structure and not another. But pronunciation is the fact; spelling is just a standard representation. And eye dialect spelling is not even that.

Comment: [I Wanna New Room](http://www.amazon.com/Wanna-Room-Karen-Kaufman-Orloff/dp/0399254056), by Karen Kaufmann Orloff.

Comment: I.e, to spell it out. There is no "Right" or "Wrong" about non-standard spelling; only about standard spelling.

Comment: Well, [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wanna) mentions both _want to_ and _want a_.

Comment: After realizing the the mistake I made, now I agree with you.

Comment: Please, check my edited answer.